# Как избавиться от задержки при передаче данных в arduino через последовательный порт?

Tags: python, arduino

Здравствуйте, никак не могу найти решение простой задачки активации пина на ардуино через вызов функции в python.
Проблема в том, что возникает задержка в полсекунды из за (как я понял) ожидания готовности микроконтроллера. Можно ли избежать задержек?

Python

```
import serial, time

ON = ":00000008f8"

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600)
time.sleep(0.28) // если убираю здесь, то пин не активируется
#ser.flush()
ser.write(ON)
time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

Arduino:

```
const int pin =  2;

void pulseLed() {
   digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);        // sets the pin on
   delay(200);        // pauses for 50 microseconds      
   digitalWrite(pin, LOW);         // sets the pin off
   delay(200);       // pauses for 50 microseconds
  }

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);           // set pin to input
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop()
{
  // serial read section
  while (Serial.available()) // this will be skipped if no data present, leading to
  {
    if (Serial.available() >0)
    {
      pulseLed();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Данная проблема проиходит не из-за ожидания готовности микроконтроллера, а из-за ожидания порта. Единственный способ, как это получилось победить, это использовать задержку как у вас, и держать порт постоянно открытым пока он необходим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня Arduino Nano перемычки нет, выпаял резистор C4 но устройство стало лагать и вести себя непредсказуемо, поставил поставил резистор между +5 и GND все стало работать как часики. Кому интересно ссылка на библиотеку: [FireBox - a simple way to connect Arduino with Python](https://github.com/thisroot/firebox)

Answer (score 2):

Когда хост обращается к последовательному порту Ардуино (вызов функции `serial.open()`), происходит так называемый мягкий сброс (soft reset) микроконтроллера. При этом запускается бутлоадер Ардуино, который некоторое время ждёт, не поступит ли от хоста специальной последовательности символов для запуска программы загрузки новой прошивки.

Поскольку специальная последовательность не поступает, то бутлоадер передаёт управление прошивке пользователя, запуская Ваш скетч.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы микроконтроллер ждал запуска программы на хосте и не сбрасывался при открытии последовательного порта, то Вам следует удалить перемычку soft reset на Вашей плате Ардуино.

Без этой перемычки при загрузке скетча в Arduino IDE надо будет вручную нажимать кнопку сброса, чтобы запустить бутлоадер.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics работает только с некоторыми поправками, читайте ответ ниже.